# COMException after upgrading DTS package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssis, dts

After I upgraded our dts-packages with the VS2013 upgrading wizard, following exception occurs when I try to execute the package:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll

Additional information: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
```

I couldn't find a solution that works for me...
Many people suggest to switch the property Run64BitRuntime to false, but this didn't help.

Do you have any tips how I can resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try removing and readding `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS` dll?

Comment: I found the solution to the problem: As you suggested correctly, I had to readd the ManagedDTS.dll and the DTSRuntimeWrap.dll in the correct versions. I had to downgrade to VS2012 tough, because there wasn't a 64bit version of DTSRuntimeWrap.dll. Everything works fine now, thanks! :)

Comment: I add this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing and readding `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS dll`.

Sometimes this should solve this kind of problems!